# SQL error when migrating data

Tags: sql-server

I am currently trying to migrate databases from one server to the next, I am using a VPN to remote into one server and I am trying to move this data onto another sql server on a remote desktop server. I have been at this for a while and keep getting this error:

[image]

I am puzzled by this, because SQL authentication to log into the server where the data is located on and I use Windows Authenticaion to log onto the target server, If i try and use sql authentication it wont work, but if I type something into the username and password and then still select windows auth then the error will display whatever I typed into the username, like it needs to be sql authentication. I am not sure what to do, I tried messing with the TCP/IC ports and destination ports and I even tried connecting to the VPN on both my computer and the remote client so that I could ping both servers so I know that they can atleast communicate. My only other idea to solve this is to mess with the Server Browser and the logins stored there but im not exactly sure what im doing there and dont want to mess anything up. I am not sure what to do next so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify that you do have the proper login and permissions for both servers and **make sure** that the server is configured to accept that authentication form.

Check you server settings.

[image]

Comment: I switched my target server from windows only to sql and windows both but still no go, what permissions would I need to be able to do this?

Comment: you need to have a valid login in both servers, and you need to have create database in the target server. depending on the copy method you use (detach database) will determine the permissions you need in the source server. if you use the detach approach, both servers need access to the shared network location.

Comment: umm... you are in a VPN. Is you computer (running Management Studio) joined to the same domain the server is? is the server on a different domain?

Comment: So I can log in with SQL Authentication on the server that I am transfering the data from, but I cannot log in through SQL authenticaion on my target server, I can only do it with windows authenticaion, is that the problem? And I am not using the server management object not detach

Comment: it sounds like that is your problem. Your desktop computer is on a different domain the server is. that is why it reject your credential. you dont have permissions on the target server.

Comment: My first sever ( the one I am transferring from) is on the VPN, the second server that I want to transfer to is not on the VPN, Its a server I get to through a remote desktop connection, so I do not think they are on the same domain

Comment: simple. the domain of your desktop is "ENTERPRISE" (from the screenshot). go to the target server and look for the domain it is joined to.

Comment: Ok i got this issue figured out, but now when I finish the migration I get an error when trying to Execute SQL Server Agent. It says "The Job Failed. Check event log on the destination server for details" And im not sure how to fix this one.

Comment: did you checked the event log? and... that sounds like a different problem. could you please acept the answer or elaborate on what the solution was?